# Exporting CSV File to C# with a line breaks in cells

Tags: c#, excel, csv, export-to-csv

My application is extracting data from a CSV excel file and distribute each lines in an array of string, and then distributes the array of string to another array of string to form a cell, right? here's my problem, some of the lines that has been extracted and distribute to an array of string from the csv file is cut short, and does not collect the array of strings completely. and we noticed that that array of string when we looked it inside the excel has a cell that has a line break:

[image: Cells that have 2 lines]

here is the C# code when extracting the csv file's lines to an array:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
```

Comment: try using `String[] lines= File.ReadAlllines` The first line can be accessed by using lines[0] and the second line with lines [1]

Comment: ReadAllLines is not enough. Excel will export this cell with a line break in it. So you have to carefully parse quotes and within a quoted string don't take line feeds as record separators.

Comment: The `lines` in the code is an array which consists of the rows of the excel file, but the line that I'm talking about is line break inside a cell. i want to eliminate does line break without touching the excel file before it parse to the array string variable `lines`.